# Selector for elements that contains elements of a class

Tags: css

Is it possible to select the elements of a type that contains element with a determined class?

Example:

```
<div class="myLabel"">
     <label class="PageTitle" tabindex="-1">en la san fan the la patriki</label>
</div>  
<div class="myLabel"">
     <label tabindex="-1">other san fanes</label>
</div>
```

I want the first div to be returned but not the second. Something like this:

```
 div.myLabel:haschild([class*="PageTitle"])
```

Comment: Can't do it with css currently, not reliably at least

Comment: Not yet... Try Js. Take a look at JQuery `.has()` - http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: @Huangism I don't want to search the parents for  set of given elements. I want discard some elements from a set I already have. But yes, maybe these are the both sides of the same coin.

Comment: @Adminiculo yes same thing, you can't modify the parent based on its children using css reliably

Comment: @LcSalazar I was hoping to solve the matter only editing the styles file. Running a script would fix it but it would be hard to maintain.